# respond_with and namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Tricky issue...

Assume the following models:

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
class Foo::Nut < ActiveRecord::Base
```

The following route:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :bars do
    resources :nuts do
```

In the create action for nuts at /admin/bars/100/nuts, I create the model based on post data and would like to respond with:

```
@respond_with(:admin, @bar, @nut) (where bar and nut had been set up in the action)
```

I'm presented with this lovely error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `admin_foo_bar_foo_nut_url')
```

I'd like rails to look for admin_bar_nut_url and not admin_foo_bar_foo_nut_url.

Any ideas if I can get around this? Clearly something up with having my models define in modules...

Would prefer to have to abandon the model namespacing but can if I must.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm having the same problem except that my "Foo" would be "Admin" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you need to go away with name space rather than using respond_to instead of respond_with

```
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(admin_bar_nut_url(@bar, @nut)) }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove **foo** from your routes, override `model_name` in your models like:

```rb
class Foo::Bar < ApplicationRecord
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, Foo)
  end
end
class Foo::Nut < ApplicationRecord
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, Foo)
  end
end
```

This will result in `Foo::Nut.model_name.route_key` being "nuts" instead of "foo_nuts"

And now `respond_with` should work as desired.